# Is there a better term for a groceries divider bar?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm Flemish, and I recently read that in 2005, the Dutch dictionary added the word "beurtbalkje" (literal translation: turn cuboid) as a neologism for the little plastic or wooden thing that you can put between your groceries and those of the previous or next customer. I think this is such a nice word for it, beautifully simplistic and yet rather obvious what's it's supposed to mean. The alliteration is also a nice touch.

However, I can't find a similarly appealing word in English. The literal translation sounds obscure. Groceries divider bar is a bit long to ask. I found "checkout divider" on Wikipedia, which is somewhat better, but it just doesn't sound as nice as the Dutch word "beurtbalkje".

Is there a better name in English than "checkout divider"?

Comment: Everyone I know just calls it a ***bar***, since context almost always makes it screamingly obvious *which* [type of] bar you're talking about.

Comment: It's referred to as a "divider" or just "stick" where I shop.  "May I have the divider?" is how I usually ask the shopper ahead of me in line.

Comment: You know, not everything needs to have an official name.

Comment: So it's not just here that those things are famous for being a practical linguistic gap, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to the bar that  is generally called:

[Next-customer bar](https://www.google.it/search?q=next%20customer%20bar&espv=2&biw=1277&bih=644&tbm=isch&imgil=LS4mrPNWRa-8eM%253A%253BXEWkXu-TJncw_M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.965malls.com%25252Fcategory%25252Fpromos%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=LS4mrPNWRa-8eM%253A%252CXEWkXu-TJncw_M%252C_&usg=__OUO14jo-gYZv3CLFjwbk379IGqI%3D&dpr=1&ved=0CDgQyjc&ei=vLG_VImuFs_zarztgYgK#imgdii=LS4mrPNWRa-8eM%3A%3BS2aZebK5YJ4BOM%3BLS4mrPNWRa-8eM%3A&imgrc=LS4mrPNWRa-8eM%253A%3BXEWkXu-TJncw_M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.965malls.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F07%252Fsultan-center-nbk-promo.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.965malls.com%252Fcategory%252Fpromos%252F%3B1296%3B968):

> - One of the most used plastic products in  supermarkets are "Next Customer" bars.

[image]

Comment: The ones I see are covered in adverting. I suppose it is fairly obvious what they are. Why don't we just call them *things*?

Comment: @WS2  -  I avoided posting one covered with advertising, but yes, they are more and more used to advertise products.

Comment: I was surprised to find how accepted this compound has become. You could add a couple of relevant links.

Answer (score 1):

If Google can be trusted, I would suggest ***[checkout divider](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/checkout_divider)*** as Wiktionary has it. *Divider* is the most commonly appearing word in all the variant names used by advertising companies and manufacturers that appear in a search: *grocery divider*, *checkout lane divider*, *lane divider*, and so on, but the largest number of image results, for example, come up for *checkout divider*.

But Google is fickle, so I checked filings with the U.S. Patent & Trademark Office, and here too, *checkout divider* was the common element. From 1984 we have a patent for the *[check-out counter divider](http://www.google.com/patents/US4534126)* (#US 4534126 A); thence to the *[checkout counter order divider](http://www.google.com/patents/US5450926)*, *[retail checkout divider](http://www.google.com/patents/US5933994)*, and simply *[checkout divider](http://www.google.com/patents/US7284347)*— plus *[checkout counter divider bar tracks](http://www.google.com/patents/US6148960)*.

For what it's worth, *checkout divider* is also offered in translation dictionaries as the English counterpart to *[séparateurs de caisse](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/checkout%20divider)*, and *checkout [lane] divider* or *grocery divider [bar]* for [der Warenteiler, der Warentrenner, & der Kundentrenner](http://www.dict.cc/english-german/checkout+divider.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have just asked the staff in a very large supermarket in Manchester, Fallowfield. Sainsburys call them either ***till dividers*** or ***customer dividers***. But on the list of equipment staff can requisition they appear simply as ***divdrs***, or something close to that.